# Why is my insert function running twice?

Tags: php, mysql, admin

I have a simple function that creates an admin login. It checks if the password equals the confirmed password. What happens though is when you type the confirm password wrong and it'll say the passwords do not match, when you type the correct confirmed password, it'll go through and create the admin login and enter in the mysql table twice...if I end up putting the password and confirmed password in correctly only once, it'll go through and insert into the table once. What is going on?

My Jquery:

```
$('#create_adminForm').submit(function() {

 $(this).on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {

var str = $(this).serialize();

 $('#createResponse').html('Please wait...'); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "inc/functions.inc.php?action=createAdmin",
            data: str,
            success: function(data){ // if success then generate the div and append the the following

                        if(data == "false confirm") {
                            //if passwords do not match
                    $('#createResponse').html('Passwords do not match!'); 
                    $('.login-box').effect( "shake" ); 
                    }
                    if(data == "created") {
                        //else - the account is created! verification email  has sent
                        $('#createResponse').html('Account created!');

   $('#general_modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
        $('#insertModalHeader').html('Account Created');
            $('#modalContent').html('Admin Account has been created! Please check your email to activate the account. <br><Br> You will be now redirected to the login page...');

                    }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) { //this is to check if there is any error
                alert("status: " + status + " message: " + error);
            }
        }); 



     }); 

   });
```

My php:

```
if($_GET['action'] == "createAdmin") {

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'); 
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username'); 
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'); 
$confirm = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'confirm_password'); 

$current_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s a");
$microTime = microtime();


if($password == $confirm) {

$hash_pass = crypt($password .$microTime);

$pass_crypt =  crypt($password); // let the salt be automatically generated

$statement_insertAdmin = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO admin_login(username, password, email, created_date, hash)
VALUES(:user, :pass, :email, :created, :hash)");
$statement_insertAdmin->execute(array(
"user" =>  $username,
"pass" => $pass_crypt,
"email" => $email,
"created" => $current_date,
"hash" => $hash_pass
));

//send verification email with hash
$to = $email; 
$subject = "Admin Account Created";

$htmlbody = 'Please click the link below to activate your admin account! <br><Br>

    <a href=\'http://www.companyname.com/admin/activate.php?  a=1&h='.$hash.'\'>
  Activate Now </a>  
 ';


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

 // More headers
$headers .= 'From: Company Name<email@email.com>';

mail($to,$subject,$htmlbody,$headers);

echo "created"; 

}

else {
echo 'false confirm';       
}

}
```

Comment: probably the script is being CALLED twice. go check your server's access log to see what's happening.

Comment: Just as an FYI, it's better to use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). It's like crypt, but in a compact wrapper that does the work for you

Comment: I can't use password_hash on my current hosting server.

Comment: @Mike Has the first row inserted empty pwd and empty confirm?

Comment: @Sefran - When I enter the password and confirm password correctly, it'll run and insert into the table once. But when i test it and do an incorrect confirm password, and then put the correct password and submit the form, it'll insert into the table twice.

Comment: @Mike Be sure to not resubmit the form, for example try to display another page. Try `if ($_GET['action'] == "createAdmin" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // …
}`

Comment: Just in case: I've seen this happen when AJAX is used to submit a form that has a client-side plugin attached more than once. In those cases, the call will run as many times as the plugin was attached to it.

Comment: I just updated the code above to show the jquery part.

Comment: @Sefran2 - I just tried that and it is the same result.

Comment: What do you have in your form's 'action' attribute?

Comment: <form id="create_adminForm" data-abide="ajax" method="post" action="#" >

Comment: If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: I figured something else out: When i test out my form and type in the password and confirm password wrong on purpose and press the submit button, it will do a jquery shake once saying the passwords do not match. When i press the submit button again, it'll shake twice, press it again, it'll shake 3 times, etc.. when i press the submit button up to the 5th time, it'll shake 5 times lol. Then i match the passwords, and it'll insert into my table 5 times...how is it doing that??